# How to avoiding repeating work (or to keep common/shared state) in nested hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In a nested hook: how could one know if it already was invoked in the current component (instance) and access any previously computed/saved values?

Preferably without the `Component` author/the hook user having to know about this and not having to do anything special for it to work.

#### Example

An example to illustrate the problem:

```js
const useNestedHook = () => {
    // Some heavy work with the same result for each component instance.
    // Is it possible to remember the result of this work when
    // this hook is used again in the same component instance?

    // So I would like to save a state which all uses of useNestedHook
    // could access as long as they are in the same component instance.
}

const useHookA = () => {
    useNestedHook();
};

const useHookB = () => {
    useNestedHook();
};

const Component = () => {
    useHookA();

    // Would like to avoid useNestedHook repeating its work since it's
    // used in the same component and would have this same result (per definition)
    // Preferably without the Component author having to know anything about this.
    useHookB();
};
```

#### Imagined solution

Something like a "named" shared state, which would give access to the same shared state (in the same component instance) no matter which hook it's used in. With each component instance having its own separate state as usual. Maybe something like:

```js
const [state, setState] = useSharedState("stateId", initialValue);
```

Comment: I could imagine how one could build such a shared state if there was a way to access some kind of id for the current component instance that the hook is used in. Is there a way to do that in React?

Comment: Maybe with redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Each `useState()` call will always be separate from other `useState()` calls.

The component can not use the hooks as in your example, but the component author doesn't necessarily have to care for the implementation details.

A solution would depend on the use case.

### Some details:

One state is defined by where the `useState()` call is written in the code (see [explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation)), which is not directly related to the instance. I.e. two `useState()` calls and two instances are 4 state values.

You can use **shared state** e.g. using [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), but then the state would also be shared by all instances, not only the hooks (which you don't want).

So the `useNestedHook()` will always be "separate", but if you can use shared state, and you only care for **"caching"**, and can accept that the `useNestedHook()` is called twice (i.e. skip the expensive operation if the result is the same), then you can use [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect). I.e. the call would depend on the **value**, not the instance and not the hook.

### Some examples:

#### 1. One hook with options

E.g. if your hooks `A` and `B` would optionally calculate two different values, which need the same `useNestedHook()` value, you could create one hook with options instead, e.g.:

```
const useHookAB = ({ A, B }) => {
  const expensiveValue = useNestedHook();
  if( A ){ /* do what useHookA() was doing */ }
  if( B ){ /* do what useHookB() was doing */ }
};

const Component = () => {
    useHookAB({ A: true, B: true });
};
```

I can't imagine another reason right now why you would want to call the hooks like that.

#### 2. The "normal" way

The obvious solution would be:

```
const useHookA = ( value ) => {
  // ...
};

const useHookB = ( value ) => {
  // ...
};

const Component = () => {
    const value = useNestedHook();
    useHookA( value );
    useHookB( value );
};
```

But I can imagine reasons why you can't (or don't like to) do it that way.

Comment: Hooks `A` and `B` may not really know of each other, and can be used independently. And it would be nice if the end user of these hooks doesn't have to know about their internals (the "nested" hook).

Comment: Ok, I understand. I added some more details to my answer. (Probably still no optimal solution for you).

Comment: If it possible to use context without a wrapping the component in the context provider, then that could possibly work. But I guess you can't use context that way. Thanks for your input!